# Issue with special characters in Glassfish/Java EE6/MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8, glassfish, arabic

I am working on a small application that stores data in a MySQL database.
The data is various fields, some are in Turkish, Russian or Arabic. When inserting new record it is saved in the database in "??????" and other wired chars.

The architecture of the application is like this

JSP Form -> Servlet -> EJB -> JPA(EclipseLink) -> Glassfish (JDBC Pool <-> JDBC Resource)->MySQL

I already :

- Changed the database and all tables and fields encoding to UTF-8
- I added the "**?CharSet=utf8&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8**" to the URL of the database in the jdbc pool config in glassfish

But the issue didnt get solved

Comment: Hey did you find any reasonable solution for that. I am stuck in similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue, before dealing with the request paramters, just insert:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

And every thing will be ok

[Link where I found the solution](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q4)

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to see only one source of trouble (maybe you omitted it in your question): I don't see the source encoding being considered.
From the JSP Form the user fills, you should somehow get the character set the data was encoded in; then, in the Servler or EJB you convert that data in your destinarion character set (utf-8) before storing it in the database (Java offers some API for this task, but I never used them directly so I can't give you any example).

I don't know about the parameters you added to the JDBC url, so I can't comment on them.